# How output data with gzip header and not deflate header

Tags: php

I'm testing compression of html files.

I have 2 HTML files:

1. Not compressed HTML file ( content will change )
2. Compressed HTML file .gz ( content won't change )

Using PHP I'm trying to output compressed files data and here begins.

test with already compressed html file.

```
//header gzip
$data = getfile($name); // custom function packed with fopen fread
header(Content-Encoding: gzip); // header works perfect
echo $data; // output OK

//header deflate
$data = getfile($name); // custom function packed with fopen fread
header(Content-Encoding: deflate); // file was gzip compressed so error is normal
echo $data; // fireFox : Content Encoding Error
```

test with not compressed html file

```
//header gzip using gzcompress();
$data = gzcompress(getfile($name), 9); 
header(Content-Encoding: gzip); // somehow header is bad
echo $data; // fireFox : Content Encoding Error , but IE 9 output OK
```

but here we got magic

```
//header deflate using gzcompress();
$data = gzcompress(getfile($name), 9); 
header(Content-Encoding: deflate); // header works perfect
echo $data; // Firefox output OK, but IE output ERROR
```

How fix this crazy thing and send all data as gzip with gzip header not defalte? maybe someone have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP spec. ([RFC2616](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2616#section-3.5)) says:

> gzip

> ```
>     An encoding format produced by the file compression program
> ```

```
    "gzip" (GNU zip) as described in RFC 1952 [25].
```

> compress

> ```
>     The encoding format produced by the common UNIX file compression
> ```

```
    program "compress".
```

> deflate

> ```
>     The "zlib" format defined in RFC 1950 [31] in combination with
> ```

```
    the "deflate" compression mechanism described in RFC 1951 [29].
```

The [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) say:

> gzcompress

> ```
>    For details on the ZLIB compression algorithm see the document
> ```

```
   "ZLIB Compressed Data Format Specification version 3.3"
   (RFC 1950).
```

> gzdeflate

> ```
>    For details on the DEFLATE compression algorithm see the document
> ```

```
   "DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3"
   (RFC 1951).
```

> gzencode

> ```
>    For more information on the GZIP file format, see the document:
> ```

```
   GZIP file format specification version 4.3 (RFC 1952).
```

From this, one can come to the conclusion that `gzencode()` must be used with `gzip`, and `gzcompress()` (with the `DEFLATE` encoding) must be used with `deflate`.

The first combination works for me. I haven't tried the second; don't know why it wouldn't work with IE. A URL might help to trouble-shoot that problem.